# Is there a technical name, grammatically, for the use of "it" in a non-specific way?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, indefinite-pronouns

A year or more ago, someone on this website used a word which I cannot now recall. He or she used the word to describe how the word *it* is often used in a non-specific way and with no clear referent.

My first question is:

> What might have been the descriptive word--or words--this person used to describe that particular use of *it*?

My second question arises from a verbal habit I've been trying to break myself of lately, and that is the *overuse* of the word *it*, particularly when the word has no clear referent. My second question, then:

> Is my attempt worth the effort?

Frankly, I've sort of enjoyed the process of wording sentences without using the word *it* overmuch, but as with my effort of limiting my use of the locution "due to the fact that," I am beginning to wonder, however, if my efforts are worth it. (Oops, I've used the word *it* unnecessarily! As President Reagan would say, "There you go again . . ..")

To ground my question in reality, here are a couple of sentences which use the offending word *it* somewhat amorphously, each of which is followed by a sentence without the offending word:

> - How far is it from New York City to Los Angeles?

- What is the distance between New York City and Los Angeles?

> - To me it seems the idea is quite do-able.

- I think the idea is quite doable.

> - Whenever it occurs to you, please write me a letter.

- Whenever you think of writing a letter to me, please do so.

The above sentences are the best I could come up with on short notice, so they may not be perfect exemplars, but I hope they serve at least to illustrate the "amorphous it."

Comment: Are you thinking of "dummy" it? Or possible "weather" it?

Comment: @BillJ: I don't think so, Bill. Don

Comment: 'Semantically empty'?

Comment: A form of 'demonstrative it'?

Comment: @PaulM: Sounds good to me, but I don't think that's it. Don

Comment: @AmI: I don't know what a "demonstrative it" is, but I don't think that was the expression the person used. Don

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are thinking of [expletives](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/572/04/):

> Expletives are phrases of the form *it* + *be-verb* or *there* + *be-verb*.
>   Such expressions can be rhetorically effective for emphasis in some
>   situations, but overuse or unnecessary use of expletive constructions
>   creates wordy prose. Take the following example: "It is imperative
>   that we find a solution." The same meaning could be expressed with
>   this more succinct wording: "We must find a solution."